# C# Can I pass more than one data into my target method when using ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (WaitCallback, Object)` to start a thread with my target method and data. Can I pass more than one data into my method? the second parameter in `QueueUserWorkItem (WaitCallback, Object)` can be an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a example of using a class so you can get strongly typed pramaters

```
public class CreateUserTaskInfo
{
    public string username { get; };
    public string password { get; };
    public string sqlServer { get; };
    public string database { get; };
    public string practice { get; };
    public RemoteUserManager client { get; };
    public CreateUserTaskInfo(RemoteUserManager cli, string usr, string pass, string sql, string db, string prac)
    {
        client = cli;
        username = usr;
        password = pass;
        sqlServer = sql;
        database = db;
        practice = prac;
    }
}

public void ExampleFunction(...)
{
    //gather up the variables to be passed in
    var taskInfo = new CreateUserTaskInfo(remote, user, password, SqlInstancePath, AccountID, practiceName);

    //queue the background work and pass in the state object.
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RemoteUserManagerClient.CreateUser), taskInfo);
}

static public void CreateUser(object stateInfo)
{
    CreateUserTaskInfo ti = (CreateUserTaskInfo)stateInfo;

    //use ti in the method and access the properties, it will be 
    // the same object as taskInfo from the other method
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter can be an array but you're better off creating a custom class for containing your data.  That way the data you pass is fully typed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the type of the argument is System.Object so you can pass anything. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Just cast your state object back, which also applies for [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx):

```
List<string> list = new List<string> {"1","2","3"};
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (CallBack, list);

void CallBack(object state)
{
    List<string> list = (List<string>) state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All types in .NET derive from object so you can pass in anything you want to QueueUserWorkItem.  Just cast it in your WaitCallback method.

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient method is to use a lambda expression:

```
var localVariable = 42;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (_ => { Console.WriteLine(localVariable); }, null);
```

This is the most sane way to use this API.

The C# compiler will generate a class internally. This method is (virtually) as fast as using a class explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lambda expression is indeed the easiest way.

However, not using the state argument of the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to pass along arguments should be considered an anti-pattern:

The following consistently works in my app:

```
var parm = new ParallelInput()
                        {
                            threadIdNbr = threadId,
                            input = input,
                            inputLength = inputLen,
                            leftBlock = leftBlock,
                            leftBlockLength = leftBlockLength,
                            leftSiblingThreadData = leftSiblingThreadData,
                            rightSiblingThreadData = rightSiblingThreadData, 
                            threadCommon = threadCommon,
                            globalOutputWriter = globalOutputWriter,
                            threadWrittenAllCounter = threadWrittenAllCounter
                        };

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(pp => { var p = (ParallelInput)pp; rdr.parallelConvert(p.threadIdNbr, p.input, p.inputLength, p.leftBlock, p.leftBlockLength, p.leftSiblingThreadData, p.rightSiblingThreadData, p.threadCommon, p.globalOutputWriter, p.threadWrittenAllCounter); }, parm);
```

... and the following consistently fails on my hardware :

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => rdr.parallelConvert(threadId, input, inputLen, leftBlock, leftBlockLength, leftSiblingThreadData, rightSiblingThreadData, threadCommon, globalOutputWriter, threadWrittenAllCounter), null);
```

... since it fails to provide all data within the input array.
(Tested with VS2010 and .NET v4.0.30319)